# Import nested JSON data from from API into a single table in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have some nested JSON data that I get from a API URL that I need to store into a single table in SQL Server, but I have not been able to find a solution that does not involve using multiple tables.

What I have, and what I have tried below this:

This is the JSON data I get from API:

```html
{
    "Localnumber":"8888",
    "Name":"Some Name",
    "Description":null,
    "Email":"some@email.com",
    "PhoneNumbers":[
       {
          "Number":"88888888",
          "LineName":null,
          "BelongsTo":"8888",
          "GotoLocalNumber":null
       },
       {
          "Number":"22222222",
          "LineName":null,
          "BelongsTo":"8888",
          "GotoLocalNumber":null
       }
    ],
    "Phones":[
       {
          "LocalNumber":"200000",
          "Name":null,
          "Type":21,
          "MAC":null,
          "BelongsTo":"8888",
          "description":"Myfone"
       },
       {
          "LocalNumber":"200001",
          "Name":null,
          "Type":8,
          "MAC":"22222222",
          "BelongsTo":"2931",
          "description":"Mobile (22222222)"
       },
       {
          "LocalNumber":"200002",
          "Name":null,
          "Type":23,
          "MAC":null,
          "BelongsTo":"8888",
          "description":"Some Description"
       }
    ],
    "Info":[
       {
          "Type":0,
          "Label":null,
          "Value":null
       }
    ],
    "Department":null
 }
```

I have tried in the small just to see if I could get some data from it using the below:

```
DECLARE @JSON varchar(max)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'https://public.somedomain.net/api/employee?account=XXXX&hash=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', SINGLE_CLOB) import
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
WITH 
(
    [Localnumber] varchar(20), 
    [Name] varchar(20), 
    [Description] varchar(20), 
    [Email] varchar(20) 
)
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Cannot bulk load because the file "https://public.sippeer.dk/api/employee?account=8493&hash=1SORJvBGzfCMXvc2kwGfbbC-HTIkJd" could not be opened. Operating system error code 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).

Any help that can just get me "on track" of solving this is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't open a url like that, Windows file system does not do urls. Write a Powershell script that downloads it and passes it in as a parameter.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface .. Okay, that is bad news, but makes sense when you write it .. I need to run this from a web page (Classic ASP) on demand when Page loads, so I am not able to use PowerShell for this operation .. Maeby I should try to find a way to read it using VBScript in ASP and insert it to the table using a two step .. I just hoped I could do it in a one step SQL Query. Thank you for your guidance :-)

Comment: Same principle: just download the url client-side (in ASP) and pass it through to such a query as a parameter. Ideally you shouldn't be using Classic ASP, it's really old and has had no updates for a very long time

Comment: @Chalieface ..  allright, that is a great idea passing it as a parameter, I will try that tomorrow :-) .. I am using ASP Classic as it is the language I used to work with when I was programming fulltime, over 20 years ago, and still use it for hobby programming .. but it is on my to-do list to learn a new language when time is for it, but with fulltime work and being a single dad .. well time is not so much :-D